# Get the data from all children in firebase using swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database. It looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
ref.child("2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        let latitude = dict["Latitude"] as Any
        let longtitude = dict["Longtitude"] as Any
        print(longtitude)
        print(latitude)
    })
```

My problem is that my code retrieves the data from only the child called `2`. How can I make it retrieve the data from all the children?

If you have any questions just let me know. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to attach the observer one level higher in the JSON, and then loop over the child nodes:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    for case let child as FIRDataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
        guard let dict = child.value as? [String:Any] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        let latitude = dict["Latitude"] as Any
        let longtitude = dict["Longtitude"] as Any
        print(longtitude)
        print(latitude)
    }
}
```

Loop syntax taken from [Iterate over snapshot children in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341888/iterate-over-snapshot-children-in-firebase), but also see [How do I loop all Firebase children at once in the same loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719083/how-do-i-loop-all-firebase-children-at-once-in-the-same-loop) and [Looping in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023471/looping-in-firebase)

Comment: You are my hero. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to `ref`

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        Array(dict.values).forEach {
           let latitude = $0["Latitude"] as? String
           let longtitude = $0["Longtitude"] as? Int
           print(longtitude)
           print(latitude)
        }
})
```

Comment: Yes i changed it. My ref look like this: `let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Mosok")`