# How to get all child data from firebase without knowing the path

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data structure looks like this:

[image: Data structure]

I want to be able to access every users listings to make an array of all listings however I do not know every users ID or Listing ID so i can not do:
`Database.database().reference.child("users").child(uid)......` because it is not for just one UID. if there a way to 'skip' over the `.child(uid)` and `.child(listingID)` when pulling from firebase?

Comment: Database.database().reference.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
 if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
  for items in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
   let object = items.value as! [String: AnyObject]
   let email = object["email"] as! String
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve all data for all users, you can attach your observer to the entire `/users` node. That will give you a snapshot of all data in the completion handler, and you can then loop over the children of that snapshot to get at each individual user.

Something like this:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    for case let user as FIRDataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
        print(user.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value)
    }
}
```

You can use similar loops to dive further down into the snapshot's data, and more calls to `childSnapshot(forPath`: to find specific properties.

Also see the answer I gave just an hour ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638755/get-the-data-from-all-children-in-firebase-using-swift/56640036#56640036) and [How do I loop all Firebase children at once in the same loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719083/how-do-i-loop-all-firebase-children-at-once-in-the-same-loop) and [Looping in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023471/looping-in-firebase)

Comment: Thanks Frank, this was exactly what I was looking for